# Are NSF GFRP recommenders updated on the status of the application?

Tags: recommendation-letter, nsf

I applied for an NSF Graduate Research Fellowship, and was curious if my letter-writers will receive updates of my acceptance or refusal at the same time I do or if they hear anything at all after their letters are confirmed.

Comment: I don't know about GRF specifically, but generally speaking, recommenders are never informed of anything about the result of an application.  It's considered to be none of their business unless the applicant chooses to tell them.